# How to create a constructor without repeating yourself?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, constructor

Consider the following TypeScript classes:

```
class A {

  foo: string;

  constructor({ foo }: { foo: string }) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }

  equals(other: A) {
    return this.foo === other.foo;
  }
}


class B extends A {

  bar: number;

  constructor(b: {
    foo: string;
    bar: number;
  }) {
    super({ foo: b.foo });
    this.bar = b.bar;
  }
}

const b = new B({
  foo: 'Test',
  bar: 42,
});
```

In reality, class B has about 20 properties which makes the class and especially the constructor definition super verbose because every property is repeated three separate times. How could I make it more compact?

You can't do `constructor({ foo, bar }: B)` because B also requires the object to have things like `equals()`.

I also tried the following but same result:

```
constructor(b: { [K in keyof B]: B[K] }) {   
  super({ foo: b.foo });
  .
  .
  .
```

```
Argument of type '{ foo: string; bar: number; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ [K in keyof B]: B[K] }': equals.ts(2345)
```

Comment: If you insist on passing and destructuring an object, you can't really. Parameter properties would be more concise, and likely better encapsulation/grouping of parameters would reduce the overall number, but with so little context it's hard to be more helpful.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Not necessarily, I just get a lot of objects from an API and need to make them into instances of these classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a couple different approaches you can take.

### Introspect the classes themselves

Given a couple helper types, you can do

```
type NonFunctionFieldNamesOfType<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? never : K }[keyof T];
type NonFunctionFields<Tc> = Pick<Tc, NonFunctionFieldNamesOfType<Tc>>;

class A {
  foo: string;

  constructor({ foo }: NonFunctionFields<A>) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }

  equals(other: A) {
    return this.foo === other.foo;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  bar: number;

  constructor(b: NonFunctionFields<B>) {
    super({ foo: b.foo });
    this.bar = b.bar;
  }
}

const b = new B({
  foo: "Test",
  bar: 42,
});
```

You can of course also limit those types using `Pick` and `Omit` if required.

### Using `ConstructorParameters`

You can also use `ConstructorParameters` to introspect the superclass's constructor's parameters, and destructuring in the subclass's constructor.

This could be useful for more complex cases.

With `ConstructorParameters`, you could at least get to

```
  foo: string;

  constructor({ foo }: { foo: string }) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }

  equals(other: A) {
    return this.foo === other.foo;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  bar: number;

  constructor({ bar, ...a }: ConstructorParameters<typeof A>[0] & { bar: number }) {
    super(a);
    this.bar = bar;
  }
}

const b = new B({
  foo: "Test",
  bar: 42,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, if your not creating 1000's of the same instance of a class, you might find not using classes would actually work better.  I find Typescript much easier keeping things functional.  Due to Javascript scope / closures etc, I find JS classes are rarely needed.

With that in mind, your above could be simplified to something like ->

```
type AProps = {
  foo: string;
}

function A(args: AProps) {
  return { 
    args,
    equals: (p:AProps) => p.foo === args.foo
  }
}

type BProps = {
  bar: string;
}

function B(args: BProps & AProps) {
  const a = A(args);
  return {...a, args};
}

const objA = A({foo: 'fooA'});

const objB = B({foo: 'fooB', bar: 'barB'});

const objC = B({foo: 'fooA', bar: 'barC'})

console.log(objA.equals(objB.args)); //false
console.log(objC.equals(objA.args)); //true
console.log(objA.equals(objC.args)); //true
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggCgJwPZgM5QLxQN4CgpQBmSSAXFKsAgJYB2A5gNy4C%20uuhArrQMbDVJasABQBDBPVTl4yNAEoc%20KAgjBOCIdihKC4yQBodUCAEdOogDZSowsKRkpUCjAD4oYAHTEkmDFj2oXiRKbGy4oJBQAEKIjpiKBABG4uSUNAzMYVy8-ILRYhLWMbLoAGSwsfIJUDyClFCi8TAFknLMBCpqGtUEHn2i%20toEuoUhmey1tPVIiQBWME3C2N7kAOTeMKssbRN1wFAzs1HxUUsrUOskUauDyQhrd9fbzLiT03MAwidnJGsbN1A7g9xB8tnJdlMkBYIB4LEh6MJDjAPKZzFZEXMoh4AnI2lAAPT4wiWVAQV51KEwuEIw4fFFmEkY%20bYwq4xgE-FUThkt6U2HwpnI1GM2ks1p4wlcslAA)

Another advantage here of going functional, is that you get the massive added bonus of composition.  IOW: your not bounded by Javascripts OOP single inheritance model.  Of course the downside is that all typing is duck typing, eg. You couldn't for instance use `instanceOf` etc.  You would be required to do -> `if ('foo' in ...` etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, the actual class is like 200 lines with many static and non-static functions and multiple extends so this is not an option.

Comment: @leonheess Oh see, so it's an existing project your refactoring.  Yeah, moving to functional might not be trivial, but maybe something to think about in the future.  In projects I've refactored were I've removed classes and gone functional the code just feels so much easier to maintain.  Typescript and functional composition are a match made in heaven.. :)

Comment: @leonheess  `static and non-static functions and multiple extends`  <-  all that's possible using functional, but I assume you mean it would be a big job to refactor, rather than not possible. ?

Comment: It's a new project but I actually started off functional b/c I prefer it as well. However, I was forced to switch to object-oriented at some point because I was just repeating myself too much. I tried writing super generic functions but it quickly became unmaintainable :/

Answer (score 0):

The OP's goals could be best achieved by combining a low level TypeScript usage with the expressiveness of unchained JavaScript, where one much easier can use the advantages of [object-destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#unpacking_properties_from_objects_passed_as_a_function_parameter), [rest properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#rest_property) and [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) ...

The beneath posted code has its [pendant at the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-vJygde29Xq6YubSgFou2aaJOYpRZeFbuASxKAAcgAYgJN60NwAWABM7Q3wYgXEevEjoQ3m9dt-3fHjd6gx8PfhTG7cIwYl8dbQgz4QIIAAdzdcYZxbbQJ1sIQIFRSgOHDXgYgeZ4EKQlDN14C4hj-KDm1sDJM2KZ88MGYZRiI2d7i6IA)

```js
// type TParameterData = Record<string, boolean|number|string|null>;

class A {

  constructor({ foo = null, bar = null, baz = null }/*:TParameterData*/) {

    Object.assign(this, { foo, bar, baz });
  }
  equals(other/*:TParameterData*/) {
    const thisEntries = Object.entries(this);
    const otherEntries = Object.entries(other);
    return (
      thisEntries.length === otherEntries.length &&
      thisEntries.every(([key, value], idx) =>
        key === otherEntries[idx][0] && value === otherEntries[idx][1]
      )
    );
  }
}
class B extends A {

  constructor({ bizz = null, buzz = null, booz = null, ...superOptions }/*:TParameterData*/) {
    super(superOptions);

    Object.assign(this, { bizz, buzz, booz });
  }
}

const options/*:TParameterData*/ = {
  foo: 'Foo', bar: 42, baz: true,
  bizz: 'Bizz', buzz: 24, booz: false,
};
const b = new B(options);

console.log({ b });
console.log('b.equals(options) ...', b.equals(options));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

To avoid writing dozens of unnecessary lines, you do it like this:

```js
type AProps = {
    foo: string
}

class A {
    data: AProps;
    constructor(data: AProps) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

type BProps = AProps & {
    bar: string
}

class B {
    data: BProps;
    constructor(data: BProps) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

let a = new A({foo: "fooa"});
let b = new B({foo: "foob", bar: "bar"});

console.log(a.data.foo, b.data.foo, b.data.bar);
```